# TypeScript Generics: Return value of function of a index record

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

**I have the following object:**

```js
const Types = {
  'Method1': () => Method1,
  'Method2': () => Method2,
};
```

Where `Method1` and `Method2` are `class` types.

The `Types` value is a mapping from a `string` to a `Function` (to get the constructor to a type at runtime).

---

I would like to get the `ReturnType` of the function at compile-time based on the string index.

Essentially, the equivalent to this (manually) created type:

```js
type Types = {
  Method1: Method1,
  Method2: Method2,
};
```

---

I'm planning on using it like so:

```js
class Message<M extends keyof Types, T extends Types[M]> {
  request: T;
  constructor(req: T) {
    this.request = req;
  }
};

const msg = new Message(new Method1()); // <-- ERROR
```

My initial thought was to access the `ReturnType`:

```js
/* ... */
T extends ReturnType<Types[M]>
/* ... */
```

However, that doesn't seem to work since I'm getting the following error from the TypeScript compiler when calling the constructor of `Message` with `new Method1()`:

```
Argument of type 'Method1' is not assignable to parameter of type 'typeof Method1'. [2345]
```

Any hints? Thank you!

[Here is a TypeScript Playground link, with a full reproduction.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKAxgNghgzjAEBZApgFwBYHsAmBGeA3qPPAA4BOmpuAXPDKuQJYB2A5vALzwDkAZpkw8A3KAC+oUJFgIUGHACZCxMpVIK6LAK4BbAEbJyXeABYFokBJBTMLBkjRZsCbkRAkScp7XgAKAJRcAHwO8ngANCqejop0AcGhTgqRlhaoAJ6kyIk4ACqZyC7wGVmYfDnOFlLQcPAAqixMtgA8KojwyAAeqMgszvAA1sjpZRX5WTApJABKyACOWoWoHd29-bOoWuQs48jNXnkFMADaiAC6QSkhbiTk84sMdLMLS1Xu8GC2DORaYKiY5F8dxej3gzweqECNw8GCYMAAdMCIcYka8VFYrDY7MstI1bMYWMgAO71PEsXyEkkHPABfzCIA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is using [`InstanceType`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70880862/typescript-opposite-reverse-operation-of-typeof).

From the answer of Mathias Falkenberg, I learned that:

```js
const Types = {
  'Method1': () => Method1,
};
```

is equivalent to the following type:

```js
type Types = {
  'Method1': () => typeof Method1,
};
```

And therefore, since `InstanceType` is the "opposite" of `typeof`, I can get the type I need.

The final solution looks like this:

```js
class Message<M extends keyof Types, T extends InstanceType<ReturnType<Types[M]>>> {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your object

```
const Types = {
  'Method1': () => Method1,
  'Method2': () => Method2,
};
```

To a type

```
type Types = {
  'Method1': () => Method1,
  'Method2': () => Method2,
};
```

And then use the constraint that you suggested:

```
class Message<M extends keyof Types, T extends ReturnType<Types[M]>> {
  ...
}
```

With the `const Types` declaration, 'Method1' and 'Method2' are not function signatures, but actual functions returning the type of the class.

Comment: The thing is, I need the class constructor at runtime, and I only want to create a single list of all methods and not multiple. Can I create an object of the `type`, to access at runtime?